# Images not shown when publishing MVC application to virtual directory inside default web-site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, virtual-directory

I am developing an application using ASP.NET MVC 1 and VS2008. When I deploy it to the default web-site in my IIS6 on WinXP, all images are shown correctly, path to any given image is localhost/Content/ImagesUI/[image].[ext]

When I deploy it to the virtual directory, created inside the same site, any image request returns IIS standard 404 error page, while the path is localhost/[DirectoryName]/Content/ImagesUI/[image].[ext] - that seems to be correct, true?

I am mapping .* to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll in both site and directory configurations. When this mapping is removed, images are shown correctly. However, all other URLs do not work, of course.

When I am trying to open an image in browser using the URL to it, aspnet_wp.exe process is not even started (I restarted IIS to test it) - I merely get 404 or the image, depending on the presence of * mapping. Thus, I suppose it has nothing to do neither with routes registered for MVC, nor with ASP.

The solution that I found is to make Content folder a virtual directory and remove * mapping from its configuration. While that's OK to some extent, I want a better solution, which will explain and eliminate the cause of the problem, not just workaround it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please cleanup the text coz it's hard to read.

About the images - probably you have an issue with the paths to images. Show some code to see how you link to them in you MVC views.
You should be using Url.Content() HTML Helper method.

Comment: Thanks, I am using a bit more complicated logic to build an URL, but is that possible that localhost/[DirectoryName]/Content/ImagesUI/[image].[ext] is incorrect? Anyway, I will try Url.Content(), it seems to fit my needs.

Comment: I tried <%= Url.Content("~/Content/[image].[ext]")%>, no result

Comment: Hah! It's localized to having Virtual Directory name containing '.' in it. I removed the period, it works! I will certainly go on working without the period, but is there any explanation for that?

Comment: Hmm, it could some IIS6 quirks going on here.

Comment: @Michael: Please, post your solution as answer, so you can click the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah! It's localized to having Virtual Directory name containing '.' in it. I removed the period, it works! I will certainly go on working without the period, but is there any explanation for that?